# Manifest merger failed after update to gradle 2.3.0 and build tool version 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

Manifest merger failed after update to gradle 2.3.0 and build tool version 25.0.0

I have this error since the last update on android studio please help

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at AndroidManifest.xml:4:5-79
```

(and in all permissions)

And:

In the application tag I have label and theme unlighted (in red) as the string and style file was not found anymore

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: You seem to have not included your error message.

Comment: oh sorry edited txs for help !

Comment: So what does the logs say? If you have multiple errors, we need to see what those errors are.

Comment: Edited txs again :)

Comment: Missing 'name' key attribute on element `uses-permission`... Post the whole manifest, please.

Comment: the attribute 'name is missing in all my tags of the manifest not only the permission, all the activities, the persmissions, the services. It not dur particulary to the "permissions"... I only did an update and I cannot build anymore

Comment: Ok I really don't understand what had happened... I reversed my last changes and it works again txs for the help anyway. I think is a auto refactor that changed my names...